# Creating Dynamic Grouped Lists by Jquery According to Parameter

Tags: jquery

I have data which comes from ajax request. Somethink like that:

```
[
{
 "station": {
    city: 0,
    name: "A"
  },
 "geo": {}
},
{
 "station": {
    city: 0,
    name: "B"
},
 "geo": {}
},
{
 "station": {
    city: 1,
    name: "C"
},
 "geo": {}
},
{
 "station": {
    city: 1,
    name: "D"
},
 "geo": {}
}
]
```

I just want to group this according to city parameter, so if city is 0 they will be grouped Town, at the end it will be something like that:

```
        <h3>Town Stations</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>City Stations</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
    </ul>
```

I can make this if i create two different array for different type stations ( TownStations[] and CityStations[]) then assign all data according to the city parameter and create two for loop and make html.

But i wonder if is there any method directly create that kind html build with raw data?

Thanks.

Comment: Your data doesnt look right.. Can you provide the actual data?

Comment: what is "html build with raw data"? Didn't get

Comment: @Tuhin I meant that html build without make two seperate array ( from data which comes from ajax request)

Comment: @Reddy i fixed data. actual data has a number of parameter so i cant paste  here or somewhere but now it must be same.

Comment: If you are looking for a html solution, may be you should a [logic less template like mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Comment: @yigitozmen still its not right... to be clear.. count the number of `{` and number of `}` there is a mismatch.. Also if you fix it.. it looks like a object having same properties `station` many times, which again is not right..

Comment: @Redd i am sorry really. Now it must be really fixed???

Comment: @yigitozmen now it looks good.. Also after grouping how do you decide which group to go under which header?

Comment: @Reddy if i make two array according to city parameter first i create header  then print array belongs to header. If you ask me, city:0 means town city:1 means city